# python-docx Assigning text to image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have this code:

```
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading("first comparison", 4)



    # Add text:
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_text("dog 1:")

    run_2 = paragraph.add_run()
    run_2.add_text("dog 2:")

    # Add images
    image_height = Cm(8)
    image_width = Cm(5)

    paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture("./dog1.jpeg", width=image_width,
                    height=image_height)
    run_2 = paragraph.add_run()
    run_2.add_picture("dog2.jpeg", width=image_width, height=image_height)

    document.save('test.docx')
```

[image]

I would like this to be the output:
[image]

Some of my images has different width, so I don't want to manually add spaces to my text
How can I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps use a table?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I can have different width and height to each image, is there no way to calculate the image title location?

Comment: @KennySmith don't think so. agree with Nick that can be achieved using a table. table header row would contain titles and the rows below images. table cells should adjust it's width according to the size of the content within (in your case imgs). see: https://prnt.sc/xRBtS1rC6ERT . header alignment to center should solve your issue to do that in py-docx see https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdAlignParagraph.html